# Access Visual Studio 'Open With' Command via EnvDTE

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, envdte

In Visual Studio 2012, when right clicking a file in the solution explorer and clicking 'Open with...' the dialog pictured in the image below is shown:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2Wr.jpg

Is there a way to use this exact dialog window via the EnvDTE namespace? For a Visual Studio Add-in I am developing I require this functionality and would like the experience to be as similar as possible to Visual Studio (as well as to avoid writing more code...)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, this seems to work:

```
IVsUIHierarchy uiHierarchy;
uint itemId;
IVsWindowFrame frame;
VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument(myServiceProvider, fullPath, VSConstants.LOGVIEWID_UserChooseView, out uiHierarchy, out itemId, out frame);
```